# Make HTML page mobile friendly(Wix)

Tags: html, css, mobile, velo

I've started to make a page where I add my favorite movies to a list. I think it looks pretty neat on my desktop, but it looks absolutely terrible on mobile. As you probably can guess from my code, I'm not very good when it comes to frontend stuff. I'm also using Wix, so there might be some limitations there.

Anyways, this is my HTML code so far. Do you have any pointers?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9Y0VJ1YJIW6

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

td,
th {
  border: 3px solid #666666;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center; font-family:verdana, sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;font-size:60px;color: white">Favorite movies</p>
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <th style="padding:8px;font-size:30px;background-color:#dddddd;">Title</th>
    <th style="padding:8px;font-size:30px;background-color:#dddddd;">Stars</th>
    <th style="padding:8px;font-size:30px;background-color:#dddddd;">Language</th>
    <th style="padding:8px;font-size:30px;background-color:#dddddd;">Year</th>
    <th style="padding:8px;font-size:30px;background-color:#dddddd;">IMDb</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:4px;">In The Mood For Love</td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding:8px;">Cantonese</td>
    <td style="padding:20px;">2000</td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118694/">
        <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/imdb-2.png" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:4px;">Kikujiro</td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding:8px;">Japanese</td>
    <td style="padding:20px;">1999</td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0199683/">
        <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/imdb-2.png" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:4px;">Millennium Actress</td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding:8px;">Japanese</td>
    <td style="padding:20px;">2001</td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0291350/">
        <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/imdb-2.png" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:4px;">Oldboy</td>
    <td>
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
      <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/star.png" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding:8px;">Korean</td>
    <td style="padding:20px;">2003</td>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364569/">
        <img src="https://olesfavoritter.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/imdb-2.png" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is how it looks when you visit the actual site:

https://olesfavoritter.wixsite.com/movies

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: Start by having all the CSS in the stylesheet

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find the code snippet part. Thanks for correcting it!

Comment: Try using em and media queries

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! :)